# In Windows 8, how do you set the sound to persist across applications?

Tags: windows-8, audio, modern-ui

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to stop windows 8 from muting your running apps?](https://superuser.com/questions/497030/how-to-stop-windows-8-from-muting-your-running-apps)

Use case: opening up a browser for music, then switching to emacs.  But Windows 8 will mute sound from   applications that aren't "active" (the currently selected one) apparently.  How can I change this?

Comment: Any particular media playing app? Have you considered snapping it to the side?

Comment: Added Modern-UI tag since this doesn't pertain to normal desktop applications in any way.

Comment: Which browser? IE Metro or Chrome Metro?