# How can I keep audio in Windows 8.1 from fading in when I start playing a sound file?

Tags: audio, windows-8.1

Recently got an HP Windows computer running Windows 8.1.  I have installed the latest Windows updates + HP website and updated audio driver.

As a voice artist & radio commercial producer, I do audio editing.  Problem: when I start to play (any) file in Sony Sound Forge, audio, "ramps up, i.e, it doesn't begin at full volume; starts off quiet and ramps up over course of about 2-3 seconds (to finally get to full volume).  If I isolate to play just a click or pop, etc = can't hear it (no time to ramp up).

Ramping is fine for most music apps, etc. (offers nice fade in) however, not good for editing audio :-)

NOTE: discovered "Mickey-Mouse" workaround. I play a (six-hour) YouTube video (and mute it on YT) then go back into Sound Forge... in this case: now NO RAMP UP; works perfectly! (Audio then plays back just it should.)

If click **stop** on the YouTube video, hwoever = problem returns (D'oh)!

Anyone have any suggestions?

---

Addl notes:

- Using Line out (for speakers) - not my video monitor for audio.
- Using internal sound card (which I like for both recording and listening - fine quality).

Comment: Are you editing audio with the default audio chip or do you have an external sound card? Does this help http://superuser.com/questions/481127/windows-8-media-player-disable-fade-music-when-in-background. Are you playing audio via the monitor or speakers?

Comment: In what program is this happening?

Comment: Does the same issue occur using WMP? You could try using Audacity too to test it. If this is the case, you may be better asking SF directly?

Comment: I have "Mickey-Mouse" workaround. If I go to a six-hour YouTube video and click play and then mute the YouTube speaker button, and then go into my sound Forge to edit my files, it works perfectly!  audio plays back just like it should be ... however, the moment I click stop on the YouTube video, the problem returns!  does that give anyone any idea as to my issue?  I tried to find and adjust those settings in Sound Forge but I don't think that's were the problem lies.  One or 2 other programs seem to ramp up sound as well BTW.

Comment: I suggest you EDIT your question, people are not expected to read your updates in comments. This is important information. Click the edit button on your original post and add this work around to explain what you're having to do (as I assume you still want it resolved).

Comment: OK, I don't have enough rep on superuser to post an answer, so here goes:

1) Right click on the volume icon in the System Tray
2) Select "Playback devices"
3) Double click on "Speakers"
4) Click the Enhancements tab
5) Check "Disable all sound effects"
6) Click OK
7) If you are playing any sound/music, close down WMP / Winamp, wait a few seconds, then try again.

Taken from http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-pictures/automatic-volume-leveling-during-audio-playback/f9656c4a-b5e7-4cff-b029-7577f0efa549

Comment: @voicewizard Your workaround also worked for me: When I run a muted youtube video in parallel then there's no fading (in my case it's vlc on Windows 10).

Answer (score 0):

This can happen in Windows 8 and 7 if you have connected the audio to play via the monitor (computer screen, not monitor speakers) instead of speakers.

Make sure your audio is via the speakers!

Others have noted this issue with certain *external* sound cards, I'm guessing yours is internal so unlikely.

The only other option is software doing this or that it occurs as you switch to different apps (it fades out and in typically) but I don't think this is an issue for you.

Comment: Ya I'm with dave on that one, sounds like a software issue.  Either the program you're using to play the audio or some hp bundled software they've added that they "think" you need, that you don't lawl.  Could also be special software from the manufacturer that made the sound card but usually those people are good about not messing with the user experience, not always though.

Comment: I have more data and have worked out a "Mickey-Mouse"workaround.